# What happens with universal quantifications and typeclass constraints when composing functions?

Tags: haskell, lenses, rank-n-types

Lenses [can be composed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-tutorial-1.0.3/docs/Control-Lens-Tutorial.html) like any ordinary function. We have:

```
Lens' a b = forall f . Functor f => (b -> f b) -> a -> f a
```

Now consider this example:

```
(.) :: Lens' Config Foo -> Lens' Foo String -> Lens' Config String
```

Expanding we get:

```
(.) :: (forall f. Functor f => (Foo -> f Foo) -> Config -> f Config)
    -> (forall f. Functor f => (String -> f String) -> Foo -> f Foo)
    -> (forall f. Functor f => (String -> f String) -> Config -> f Config)
```

And the type of function composition is:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

Which lacks any universal quantification and typeclass constraints. Now my question is, how are these two features treated by the compiler/type-checker so that the function composition operator can be used for composing lenses?

My guess is that it is OK to have functions universally quantified and typeclass constraints, as long as these match for the two functions being composed.

Comment: As an aside, `a -> forall x. b` = `forall x. a -> b` (if `x` is not mentioned in `a` and possibly mentioned in `b`) and `a -> c => b` = `c => a -> b` (where `c` is a constraint). Note that `(forall x. a) -> b`, a rank-2 type, can’t be rewritten like this because
 the `forall`-quantified type appears in “negative position” (to the left of a function arrow).

Comment: You've made a mistake in the 2nd line - the type `Lens' X Y -> Lens' Y Z -> Lens' X Z` will never be inferred for `(.)`. This type is impredicative and GHC [doesn't support](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#impredicative-polymorphism) impredicativ polymorphism. You have an answer showing you what actually happens; the short version is every polytype is instantiated to a monotype when a function is applied, unless that function explicitly takes a polytype as an argument (i.e. with `RankNTypes`).

Comment: Oh, hey @Jon. How's your kitten?

Comment: @AaditMShah: Good, thanks. :) I’m in the middle of reorganising some code to make it easier to implement the last few major features before a release. (Trait constraints, generic trait instances, unboxed closures & arrays, a few other things.) If I can find/make the time to work on it, I *should* be able to release something in a couple months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't we see what happens? Consider the following values:

```hs
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c

foo :: Lens' A B

bar :: Lens' B C
```

The type of `foo` and `bar` will be expanded to:

```hs
foo :: Functor f => (B -> f B) -> A -> f A

bar :: Functor g => (C -> g C) -> B -> g B
```

Note that I left out the `forall f.` part because it's implicit. Also, I changed the name of `f` to `g` for `bar` to show that it's different from the `f` for `foo`.

Anyway, we'll first apply  `(.)` to `foo`:

```hs
(.)     ::                 (b      ->    c)    -> (a ->    b)     -> a ->    c
                            |            |         |       |         |       |
                         --------     --------     |       |         |       |
                         |      |     |      |     |       |         |       |
foo     :: Functor f => (B -> f B) -> A -> f A     |    --------     |    --------
                                                   |    |      |     |    |      |
(.) foo :: Functor f =>                           (a -> B -> f B) -> a -> A -> f A
```

Thus, `(.) foo` has the type `Functor f => (a -> B -> f B) -> a -> A -> f A`. As you can see, the `Functor` constraint is simply copied as is.

Now, we apply `(.) foo` to `bar`:

```hs
(.) foo     :: Functor f =>    (a      -> B -> f B) ->     a      -> A -> f A
                       |        |         |    | |         |         |    | |
                       |     --------     |    | |         |         |    | |
                       |     |      |     |    | |         |         |    | |
bar         :: Functor g => (C -> g C) -> B -> g B      --------     |    | |
                                                        |      |     |    | |
(.) foo bar :: Functor g =>                            (C -> g C) -> A -> g A
```

Thus, `(.) foo bar` has the type `Functor g => (C -> g C) -> A -> g A` which means that it's a `Lens' A C`. As you can see `Functor f` is the same as `Functor g` which is why everything works out.